# Nested divs bootstrap - doesnt respect heights the parent div

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-float

I'm trying to make a container div that have 4 or 5 child divs, each one with variant heights. And after the parent container div put a footer. The footer is apart of the parent container div, it has to occupy all the width of the screen. Somehow the parent div cuts before and doesn't respect the nested heights of the divs inside. Something its not working.

```css
body {
    font-family:freesans;
    font-weight:bold;
}


.blog_1 {
    width:100$;
    height:400px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:20px 0px;
}

.blog_slider {
    width:100$;
    height:500px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:20px 0px;
}


.thumb_index img {
    
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:black;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.thumb_index {
    display:flex;
    float:left;
}


.sl {
    background:#000;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.banner {
    background:#222;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:30px 0px;
}

.blog_faq {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:0px solid red;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    display:flex;
}

.forma_index {
    border:2px solid gray;
    height:600px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:30px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- contenido -->
  <div class="container" style=" border:1px solid green;">
    <div class="row header">
    
        <!-- logo grip -->
        <div class="col-8"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_quadro.png" class="logo"  height="100%"/>
            <a class="breadcrumb" href="">Inicio > Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="float-end img-fluid" id="grip" style="margin-top:30px;position:relative;left:-20px;cursor:pointer;" src="img/grip.png" /></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- content divs -->
    <div class="row blog_1">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Enfocados en herramientes utiles para el diseño web</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 thumb_index">
            <img src=""/>
            <h1> thumb_index Asjfn jnrf rjine frinerijnre</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 thumb_index">
            <img src=""/>
            <h1> thumb_index Asjfn jnrf rjine frinerijnre</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row blog_slider">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="sl">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="banner">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Cual es la forma de trabajo <span>+</span></h1>
            <h1>Cual es la forma de trabajo <span>+</span></h1>
            <h1>Cual es la forma de trabajo <span>+</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="banner">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="forma_index">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
 </div>
 <!-- footer -->
    <footer>
            <hr>
            <div class="footer">
                <h1>
                <span class="black">Donde estamos</span><br>Nos encontramos en la capital<br>del estado de Queretaro</h1>
                <h6>Morera 503 Col. Arboledas<br>Santiago de Queretaro 76047</h6>
                <img class="maps" src="img/maps.png"/>
            </div>

    </footer>
```

Comment: Protips: 1) You have a lot of extra CSS. Some of it's unnecessary (divs are 100% wide by default), and Bootstrap offers classes for a lot of it. 2) Inline styles are terrible. They make your layout hard to interpret and mess up your markup. Much of it can be replaced with Bootstrap classes. Don't do it. 3) Use a good editor. It'll point out mistakes like `$` in your CSS.

Comment: Does the demo above show your problem? Please revise as needed, and consider fixing some of the things I mentioned above in the process. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I remove the styles that were inline. And well i have the same problem. The parent container just dont respect the heights of its child divs. If i put a height of 3000px for that container it just show the entire layout and the footer appears in the right flow. If i remove the 3000px height of the container, the footer just shows to up and just seems like a mess.

Comment: Its already solved. I was given overflow:hidden to the parent div and not to the row div that had all the divs inside. But i just fix ordering all containers inside within diferent row divs. Thanks

Comment: Did you take the [tour]? Please provide and accept an answer below or delete your question. Note that your edit removed the placeholder images I had added, making the demo less useful.

Comment: i cant accept the answer i dont see that option. Itook the tour but i dont see that button

Comment: There _is_ no answer. I suggested that you _provide_ one. Down there. In the Answer box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the parent div (.container) had an inner div (.row) that had nested 5 divs inside. So the overflow:hidden instruction had ti be added to the (.row) div not to the parent div (.container). For that reason the layout seemed to be cutted. Otherwise i decided to fix the structure so the (.row) div repeat 5 times and then the (.container) respect all the heights inside.

```css
.blog_1 {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:50px 0px;
}

.blog_slider {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:10px 0px;
}

.blog_banner {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:10px 0px;
}

.blog_faq {
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:50px 0px;
}

.blog_form {
    width:100%;
    height:530px;
    border:0px solid gray;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:10px 0px;
}


.thumb_index img {
    
    
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:black;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.thumb_index {
    display:flex;
    float:left;
}


.sl {
    background:#000;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.banner {
    background:#222;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:30px 0px;
}


.form {
    background:#222;
    height:400px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:30px 0px;
}


.forma_index {
    border:2px solid gray;
    height:500px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:30px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- jequery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- contenido -->
  <div class="container" style=" border:1px solid green; height:100%;">
    <div class="row header">
    
        <!-- logo grip -->
        <div class="col-8"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_quadro.png" class="logo"  height="100%"/>
            <a class="breadcrumb" href="">Inicio > Blog</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4"><img class="float-end img-fluid" id="grip" style="margin-top:30px;position:relative;left:-20px;cursor:pointer;" src="img/grip.png" /></div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- content divs -->
    <div class="row blog_1">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Enfocados en herramientes utiles para el diseño web</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 thumb_index">
            <img src=""/>
            <h1> thumb_index Asjfn jnrf rjine frinerijnre</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 thumb_index">
            <img src=""/>
            <h1> thumb_index Asjfn jnrf rjine frinerijnre</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row blog_slider">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="sl">
            
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row blog_banner">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="banner">
            
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row blog_faq">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Cual es la forma de trabajo <span>+</span></h1>
            <h1>Cual es la forma de trabajo <span>+</span></h1>
            <h1>Cual es la forma de trabajo <span>+</span></h1>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row blog_banner">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="banner">
            
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row blog_form">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="forma_index">
            
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  
 </div>
 <!-- footer -->
    <footer>
            <hr>
            <div class="footer">
                <h1>
                <span class="black">Donde estamos</span><br>Nos encontramos en la capital<br>del estado de Queretaro</h1>
                <h6>Morera 503 Col. Arboledas<br>Santiago de Queretaro 76047</h6>
                <img class="maps" src="img/maps.png"/>
            </div>

    </footer>
```